# Java - temp file, that would only be in-memory

Tags: java, temporary-files

In Java how to create temporary file, that should be only in memory?

I remember some OSes have special notion of temp files, that would be clean-up automatically, and possibly would require no disk I/O at all.

Comment: Java has **temporary files** (not in memory, automatic clean-up), **memory mapped** files (not the same), and things you might find appropriate like **ByteBuffer** and **ByteArrayOutputStream**. Or you create in the OS a RAM disk

Comment: That's up to the OS, I don't think you have much direct control of it from Java since that's difficult to expose in a sane cross-platform API. You can, though, create an in memory buffer and wrap it in the standard io classes of your choice fairly easily.

Comment: mean a file in sense that it could be handled with java.io / java.nio transparently as any other file ?

Comment: @pirho well-designed IO-related classes don't work on files. They work on streams. That way, the same class can work on a ByteArrayInputStream (reading bytes in an array in memory), or on a FileInputStream (reading bytes from a file on the file system), without caring, because both implement InputStream.

Comment: @JBNizet naturally so, but i just think that this might be obvious also to OP and wonder if there is something else behind the question, but i might have misunderstood/overcomplicated the question

Comment: @pirho sorry, the previous comment was in fact for the OP.